# How do I reduce engine idling rpm without stalling it?

Tags: engine, motorcycle, rpm

Considering idling losses are present in every engine, reducing the idling rpm might be providing significant savings. But, as I noticed on my bike, the chances of engine stalling increases with reduction in idling rpm. So, is there a way, however complicated, to reduce it by any value without the engine stalling?

Assuming the ambient temperature is around 23~25 deg.

Comment: what is the current idle RPM of your engine? Anything below 1200 for a petrol engine in case of a bike and 900RPM for a car is pointless

Comment: Can you please provide the make/model/year of the motorcycle.  Different engine configurations have different minimum idle recommendations from the manufacturer.  Your chase for fuel savings regarding reduced idle will see no improvement in mileage that is measurable.  If your idle is 900 now and you reduced it by 50 rotations a minute that is 25 less times that the spark will fire per minute at idle.  The fuel savings will not be measurable.

Answer (score 5):

The issue with low idle is more significant when viewed from the perspective of oil pressure.

Reducing the idle, albeit a noble cause of saving the planet, reduces overall emissions insignificantly when compared to the implosion of an engine.  The carbon footprint related to throwing a rod and having processed oil spill out over an open uncontrolled surface are significantly higher.

Oil pressure is usually tied to engine RPM as most oil pumps are connected to the motor itself and require the engine to be working in order to provide oil pressure.  If engine RPM is reduced below suggested manufacturer settings then oil pressure could be reduced significantly as it is directly tied to engine RPM.

Answer (score 4):

You would need a heavier flywheel. If you idle too low, your flywheel doesn't have enough momentum to keep the engine running smoothly. A heavier flywheel will remedy that.

Answer (score 2):

Bikes are for driving and not to keep it idling. the best thing to do is to switch off the engine instead of keeping it idling. that will save some fuel as well!!

Comment: Not if stopped in traffic. Only when you're done riding and off the road. Far too many people not watching closely enough, and far too easy to get hit if your engine is off.